# Parsing HTML to PHP

Tags: php

I hope you can help me with the following, i have a php method to scan a directory with pictures:

```
<?php
                        $dirname = "images/";
                        $images = scandir($dirname);
                        $ignore = Array(".", "..");
                        foreach($images as $curimg){
                            if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {

                            echo "<li><a href=\"$dirname$curimg\"> class=\"portfolio-item-preview\" <img src=\"img/portfolio/portfolio-img-01.jpg\" /></a></li>\n ";

                            // echo "<li><a href=\"$dirname$curimg\"><img src=\"img.php?src=$dirname$curimg&w=300&zc=1\" alt='' /></a></li>\n ";
                                                }
                        }               
                    ?>
```

I want to put the following code after the foreach loop:

```
                            <li class="one-fourth logos">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/project2/IMG_0268.jpg" class="portfolio-item-preview" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="img/portfolio/portfolio-img-01.jpg" alt=" " width="210" height="145" class="portfolio-img pretty-box"/></a>
                        </p>
                        </li>
```

If I echo all the lines PHP generates all kinds of errors, could please someone help me with parsing the lines? I am just a beginner, sorry if it's very nooby:) I want this to create a class one-fourth logos for as long the folder contains images.

Comment: If you get the correct HTML, why not just save it to a string and then echo the entire string in the right place in the page?

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?  Is it specifically this code which produces the error?  It might be easier to put the HTML code outside of the PHP tags and embed the PHP values into it instead of embedding the HTML code into PHP `echo` statements.

Comment: Have you tried testing to see if scandir() worked? `if ($images === false) echo 'oh oh, scandir failed';` http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Answer (score 2):

Just end your php code, put the HTML and reopen php.
Like that:

```
?>
    <li class="one-fourth logos">
                    <p>
                        <a href="images/project2/IMG_0268.jpg" class="portfolio-item-preview" data-rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="img/portfolio/portfolio-img-01.jpg" alt=" " width="210" height="145" class="portfolio-img pretty-box"/></a>
                    </p>
                    </li>
<?php
```

Comment: Yeah, do it just as you prefer it.

Comment: I got it working like Jeffery A. wrote, but then the next thing: i want to use the variables $dirname and $curimg in the code like this:    <a href="' . $dirname$curimg . '" class="portfolio-item-preview" data-rel="prettyPhoto"> ,but it doesn't work. I also tried: <a href="'<?php echo $dirname$curimg; ?>'" class="portfolio-item-preview" data-rel="prettyPhoto">. But it comes with an error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I mean lke Artiifix wrote:)

Comment: Got it working!! Did it like this: <a href=" '.$dirname .$curimg.' " class="portfolio-item-preview" data-rel="prettyPhoto">

Answer (score 2):

Because your HTML doesn't contain single quotation marks (') you can put them around your HTML and it will be a valid string which you can echo:

```
echo '<li class="one-fourth logos">
    <p>
        <a href="images/project2/IMG_0268.jpg" class="portfolio-item-preview" data-rel="prettyPhoto">
        <img src="img/portfolio/portfolio-img-01.jpg" alt=" " width="210" height="145" class="portfolio-img pretty-box">
        </a>
    </p>
</li>';
```

Comment: Variables won't expand within single quotes.

Comment: @JaredBeekman Yes, and this string doesn't contain any variables so it's perfectly fine to do it this way.

Comment: @JaredBeekman I suggest you check the HTML code the OP provided. It does *not* contain any variables.

Comment: Fair enough, but the question wasn't about getting HTML errors it was about PHP. The echo'd a tag's href attribute has variables.